# What is the VB syntax to add a handler using a delegate?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In a WPF project:

I believe this C# line of code is simply adding a handler to the User Interface object and forcing the parameter to 'false' when the handler is invoked.

```
item.MouseDoubleClick += delegate { otherMethod1(false); };
```

In adding VB handlers without parameters am I correct this would be the proper syntax?

```
AddHandler item.MouseDoubleClick AddressOf otherMethod2
```

How do I express in VB a handler with parameters as in the first line above?

Comment: there isn't one as far as I know.... Either pass it forward though the default handler or wrap the control in your own control that inherits the original.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
AddHandler item.MouseDoubleClick, Sub(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
                                          otherMethod1(False)
                                  End Sub
```